# W3C validator error (Beginner at HTML5)

Tags: css, html

So I'm currently a beginner at HTML. I was writing a basic page but I was trying out a CSS file called hint.css.

I keep getting this validation error:

[image]

The Code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="hint.css" />
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>First HTML learning page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2> HTML5, <span class="hint--bottom" aria-label="Web Dev!">Learning Page 
V1.</span></h2>
    <p>Using a combination of <span class="hint--bottom" aria-
label="HTML5,CSS3,JS,JQUERY,AJAX,PHP"><b>languages.</b></span>i will 
acomplish a dynamic web site</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Put your style sheet inside the head tag

Comment: You can't have elements before the `<head>`, you before continuing your tests should read about the proper [HTML page structure](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_intro.asp)

Answer (score 2):

As @Aaron K mentioned in comment, link tags for stylesheet must be inside head. Please try the following:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>First HTML learning page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="hint.css" />
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

your link is in out of `<head></head>` tag , put it inside head tag and also

Answer (score 0):

Your link is out of `<head></head`tag, put it inside the head tag like this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="hint.css" />
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>First HTML learning page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2> HTML5, <span class="hint--bottom" aria-label="Web Dev!">Learning Page 
V1.</span></h2>
    <p>Using a combination of <span class="hint--bottom" aria-
label="HTML5,CSS3,JS,JQUERY,AJAX,PHP"><b>languages.</b></span>i will 
acomplish a dynamic web site</p>
  </body>
</html>
```